# Ant exec - Run executable from a network drive

Tags: ant

I am running the following command from my ant target:

```
<exec executable="${soa.mypath}\deploy.exe" failonerror="true" vmlauncher="false">
   <arg value="-n" />
   <arg value="${myfile}" />
</exec>
```

Where ${soa.mypath} is B:\bin.
This drive B is a network drive that I mapped on a other server.

when I connect remotly to the server where that ant script is running I can totally see and browse the B drive via the Windows explorer and the user I use is the same user that runs tha ant script.

However when I run my target, I got this error:

```
[exec] The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

Which is very weird.

Do you know if I am missing some option in the exec command?

Thank you,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Using ant 1.9.3 under Windows 8.1 I was able to get this to work with no problem with a network-mounted drive, including various combinations of forward and backslashes in the path.

My only suggestion is to replace your property with the hard-coded executable path (B:\bin\deploy.exe) in the exec task and see if that works. Also - use hard-coded path to ${myfile}.

If deploy.exe has a -version command or similar you might also try that, to rule out the problem actually being in the drive/path of ${my file}.

hth

Comment: Thank you.I am using ant 1.9.4 on windows server 2012.
I tried hard coded path even for 'myFile' and it still did not find the B drive.

Comment: I also try the -version as arg value to the deploy.exe executable to avoid any trouble by using ${myFile}, but it did not change at all the issue.